# Variadic template parameter with variadic constraint

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have a template-head of the form `template<C<T>... U>`, where `C` is a concept and `T` is a pack of types. `U` will have to be its own pack, but how exactly is this parsed?

For example https://godbolt.org/z/MhG9YqsdK:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename... T>
struct F {
    template<std::same_as<T>... U>
    static void f(U... args, void*);
};

int main() {
    F<int, char>::f(1, 'x', nullptr);
}
```

I would think that `std::same_as<T>` is a pattern for an expansion, so this expands to two template arguments, like:

```cpp
template<>
struct F<int, char> {
    template<std::same_as<int> U0, std::same_as<char> U1>
    static void f(U0 arg0, U1 arg1, void*);
};
```

Which is what clang seems to do. What gcc seems to do is transform it like:

```cpp
template<typename... T>
struct F {
    template<typename... U> requires (std::same_as<U, T> && ...)
    static void f(U... args, void*);
};
```

which makes `U` a new pack in a non-deduced context (And a SFINAE error when `U` can't be deduced and is an empty pack and `T` isn't).

Which compiler is correct? I would assume [[temp.variadic]p5](https://wg21.link/temp.variadic#5.3) is what I am looking for if this was actually a pack expansion, but I'm not sure if it applies. I also can't find where in the standard constrained variadic parameter packs are defined to see if gcc's behaviour is correct.

Comment: How **clang** can deduce `Ui`===`Ti`? I tried with **MSVC**, it's same result as **gcc**. Looking at the definition of concept `same_as<Ti,Ui>`, it is solved as `is_same_v<Ti,Ui> && is_same_v<Ui,Ti>` but **clang** uses an intrinsic in place `__is_same(Ti,Ui) && __is_same(Ui,Ti)`. I think it's why clang can deduce `Ui`===`Ti`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a GCC bug to me, it should be a pack expansion:

[`[temp.param]/17`](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#17)

> ... A type parameter pack with a *type-constraint* that contains an unexpanded parameter pack is a pack expansion. ...